# How to highlight a marker in Here.com Maps for javascript API 3.1?

Tags: here-api

How do I change the color (or some other style) of a SVG marker on pointerenter? I found some examples in 2.3, but I'm using 3.1.

Comment: When you say change the color, you mean an existing marker on the map already?

Comment: Correct.  Just like in that older example here: https://github.com/heremaps/examples/blob/master/maps_api_for_javascript/simple-examples/highlighting-a-marker.html

Comment: I'll get back to you - I'm busy this weekend so unfortunately can't work on a demo.

Comment: Looks like you got help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of highlighting `H.map.Marker` on mouse over in Javascript version API 3.1 (works for 3.0 as well):

```js
var svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="FILL_COLOR" opacity=".8"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="4" fill="black"/>
    </svg>`,
    size = {w: 30, h: 30},
    // we need to specify the correct hit area as the default one for custom icon is rectangular shape
    hitArea = new H.map.HitArea(H.map.HitArea.ShapeType.CIRCLE, [size.w/2, size.h/2, size.w/2]),
    icon = new H.map.Icon(
      svg.replace('FILL_COLOR', 'rgba(30, 200, 200, 0.7)'),
      {
        size,
        anchor: {x: size.w/2, y: size.h/2},
        hitArea
      }
    ),
    iconHover = new H.map.Icon(
      svg.replace('FILL_COLOR', 'rgb(30, 200, 200'),
      {
        size,
        anchor: {x: size.w/2, y: size.h/2},
        hitArea
      }
    ),
    marker = new H.map.Marker(map.getCenter(), {
      icon: icon,
      volatility: true // <- volatile objects re-render faster
    });

marker.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(e) {
  marker.setIcon(iconHover);
});

marker.addEventListener('pointerleave', function(e) {
  marker.setIcon(icon);
});

map.addObject(marker);
```

See it in action: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eop0d3jk/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm now using a DOM markers as a work around.  It's simpler that way.